# HostClient can't follow redirects to a different protocol, please use Client instead - 15000

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, bombardier

I am using `bombardier` for asp.net core web api performance testing. https://github.com/codesenberg/bombardier

For `http` it's works fine and giving all the result,

```
bombardier -c 128 -d 30s -l --rate 500 http://localhost:5000/
```

When I tried to do for `https` (s), then it throwing error,

```
HostClient can't follow redirects to a different protocol, please use Client instead - 15000
```

Can I use `https`? any other tool which give latency Statistics, req/res per seconds, latency distribution, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use --http1 or --http2 flag in command

```
bombardier -c 128 -d 30s -l --rate 500 <https_url> --http1
```

```
bombardier -c 128 -d 30s -l --rate 500 <https_url> --http2
```